# The best way to display data in a table

Tags: php, mysql

Getting a little bit outside my comfort zone and I'm hoping someone can explain the best way of achieving what I need.

This is a very simple staff attendance system.

The staff table includes the name of the staff member.

The attendance table includes the date and type of shift they worked (full/half/day-and-a-half) on that day.

What I now want to do is create a report as a table that shows all the staff's attendance between two dates (a pay period).

I'm thinking the first column should be the staff names, and then subsequent columns would be headed with each date between the two dates (start_date and end_date) and I then want to populate the rest of the table with the shift that a member of staff worked on a particular date.

So, it would look something like this:

```
     Name     |  2013-05-26  |   2013-05-27   |   etc
     -------------------- ---------------------------
     John     |     full     |      half      |
     Mary     |     off      |      full      |
     Peter    |     half     |      full      |
```

The following query gives me all the data:

```
SELECT a.id, first_name, last_name, attDate, staff_id, att, late
FROM staff as a LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_attendance AS b
  ON a.id = b.staff_id 
    AND b.`attDate` >= '2013-05-26' 
    AND  b.`attDate` <= '2013-06-27' 
ORDER BY last_name, attDate;
```

Which would basically be:

```
    id  |   first_name   | last_name |  attDate    | staff_id | att   |  late
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |     John       |    smith  | 2013-05-26  |     1    | full  |    0
    1   |     John       |    smith  | 2013-05-27  |     1    | half  |    0
    2   |     Mary       |    Jones  | 2013-05-26  |     2    | off   |    0
    2   |     Mary       |    Jones  | 2013-05-27  |     2    | full  |    0
    3   |     Peter      |    Doe    | 2013-05-26  |     3    | half  |    0
    3   |     Peter      |    Doe    | 2013-05-26  |     3    | full  |    0
```

So as you can see, I have all the data, I just have no idea how to get it into the table.

Any thoughts or suggestions very welcome.

Many thanks

### Graeme

Following advice from dev-null-dweller, I have the following code:

```
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=web14-fresh", $username, $password);
    $sql = "SELECT a.id, first_name, last_name, attDate, staff_id, att, late FROM staff as a LEFT OUTER JOIN staff_attendance AS b ON a.id = b.staff_id AND b.`attDate` >= '" .                   $startdate. "' AND  b.`attDate` <= '". $enddate . "' ORDER BY last_name, attDate;";
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);

    $dates = array();
    $users = array();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $dates[] = $row['attDate'];
        if (!isset($users[$row['id']])) {
            $users[$row['id']] = array(
                'first_name' => $row['first_name'], 
                'last_name' => $row['last_name'],
                'attendance' => array()
            );
        }
        $users[$row['id']]['attendance'][$row['attDate']] = $row['att'];
    }

    $dates = array_unique($dates);
    sort($dates);

    // header
    echo '<table border=1><tr>';
    echo '<td>Name</td>';
    foreach($dates as $d){
        echo '<td>'.$d.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    //data
    foreach($users as $u) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$u['first_name'].'</td>';
        foreach($dates as $d) {
            if (isset($u['attendance'][$d])) {
                echo '<td>'.$u['attendance'][$d].'</td>';
            } else {
                echo '<td>?</td>';
            }
        }
        //end row
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

This doesn't seem to be populating all the dates across the top and can't see why.
This is what I am getting.

```
    Name        2013-06-26
    Katy    ?   full
    Lauren  ?   full
    Laura   ?   full
    Louise  ?   holiday
    Jade    ?   off
```

Not quite sure the date array is not populating correctly :-/

Comment: what have you tried? do you mean you do not know how to establish a database connection, fetch the data, iterate over the results and write the data to html?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The key word there (that I couldn't remember earlier) is 'iterate'. That is exactly where I am struggling. I need suitable way to iterate through the results.

Comment: Are you looking for a table made from formatted text like you've typed, or an actual HTML table?

Comment: ok so first, you should post any PHP code you've tried. We can show you where you went wrong in the code but not many people here will want to write out a full blown example. Are you using mysqli or PDO to connect to the database?

Comment: What I am actually hoping for is a strategy of HOW to display the data. Not necessarily an example. I know how to use various means of iteration to display the data. I suppose it's how I get it into the format I described. Eg. Get the date column headings first, and then populate the appropriate columns with the data from the query results.

Comment: As you will be receiving multiple rows per staff member, I would recommend creating a php array and then inserting each with their id as the key. Then you can add each date with the date as the key. Then when you loop through the table, each members data is all in one row making it easy to put into a table row.

Comment: Iterate two times - first to create nice structured array and group dates per user and gather all possible dates. Then use gathered dates to print header and iterate through previously created array filling appropriate columns

Comment: @dev-null-dweller This sounds like what I need. Can you elaborate a little please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piece of code to illustrate my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331590/the-best-way-to-display-data-in-a-table?noredirect=1#comment25142615_17331590):

```
$dates = array();
$users = array();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dates[] = $row['attDate'];
    if (!isset($users[$row['id']])) {
        $users[$row['id']] = array(
            'first_name' => $row['first_name'], 
            'last_name' => $row['last_name'],
            'attendance' => array()
        );
    }
    $users[$row['id']]['attendance'][$row['attDate']] = $row['att'];
}

$dates = array_unique($dates);
sort($dates);

// header
//echo 'name';
foreach($dates as $d){
    echo $d;
}

//data
foreach($users as $u) {
    //echo $u['first_name'];
    foreach($dates as $d) {
        if (isset($u['attendance'][$d])) {
            echo $u['attendance'][$d];
        } else {
            // for missing records?
        }
    }
    //end row
}
```

Comment: That almost works, but it doesn't seem to populate all the dates.

Comment: All working... the above was a data issue. Many thanks for you help. G

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic output loop I use for outputting SQL results. It can be extended from here with conditional formatting based on the `$key` value or what have you.

You should also get friendly with the `printf()` and `sprintf()` functions, as they are super useful.

```
$rs; // assuming this is an indexed array of rows returned from your DB
// ie: $rs[0]['id']

$output = '<table>';

//print header row by iterating through the first result row and printing the keys
$output .= '<tr>';
foreach($rs[0] as $key => $value) {
  $output .= sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $key);
}
$output .= '</tr>';

//now the data rows
foreach($rs as $row) {
  $output .= '<tr>';
  foreach($row as $key => $value) {
    $output .= sprintf('<td>%s</td>', $value);
  }
  $output .= '</tr>';
}

$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, it doesn't address my problem specifically. And I appreciate this is down to my poor explanation. Displaying the content of a recordset is NOT the problem. Getting the data in the correct format IS the problem. Look again, at the data I have in the table and also the way I want it laid out. It's not just about displaying the data in the recordset. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Briefly:
First query only dates to create table header.
Next use your query to get data to create all rows in html table. 
And you have to remember `first_name` from previous result row. If `first_name` is changed you start new row in html table.

pseudocode (not complete):

```
$results = query("SELECT ... only dates");

// ... some html ... opening header row

foreach($results as $date) {
    echo "<td>", $date, "</td>"; 
}

$results = query("SELECT ... your query");
$last__first_name = "";

// ... some html ... closing header row and opening data rows

foreach($results as $row) {

    if( $row->first_name != $last__first_name ) {
        $last__first_name = $row->first_name;
        echo "</tr><tr>"; // create new row in html table
        echo "<td>", $row->first_name, "</td>";
    }

    echo "<td>", $row->att, "</td>"; // next column 
}

// ... some html ... closing table
```

Comment: This is closer to where I am - thank you. Am I right in thinking that this assumes that there MUST be an entry for each of the dates, for each of the people? Eg. If one entry were missing, it would throw the rest of the columns out?

Comment: yes - there MUST be entry for each of the dates - this is simplest example. maybe you could use SQL to fill empty dates - or you have to (in PHP) first change data to array data[first_name][date] and fill empty dates.

Answer (score -1):

You can echo the results in a HTML table. First, you create the headings:

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td>......</tr>';
```

Then, you execute the SQL query (the SELECT):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ... ...");
```

After this, you can iterate through the results, with "while":

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result ) ) {
echo '<tr><td>'.$row['name_of_column_1_in_db'].'</td><td>'.$row['name_of_column_2_in_db'].'</td> .......... </tr>';
}
```

Then, close the table tag:

```
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: minor note: mysql_* functions are deprecated. mysqli_* or PDO should be used

Comment: dont do this.  You are binding the model to the view.